# how to submit driver development to kernel git

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I am developing a Linux kernel driver as module, this consists of driver 'C' files, header files and modification of `Makefiles` in `drivers/misc/`.

How can I submit my development work to kernel GIT?

I assume that I have to make a patch which contains all the files related to my development.

Answer (score 2):

Please look in your kernel `Documentation/` directory and read:

- [`SubmittingPatches`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches)
- [`SubmittingDrivers`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingDrivers)
- [`SubmitChecklist`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmitChecklist)

(and `CodingStyle` while you're at it).